# how to remove the word before hyphen in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a scenario where i am getting the location value from the api(e.g:valogic-federick), I need to show only federick,but if i send it to the backend it has to  go as valogic-federick.

Iam  showing federick only but if i click the submit button at that time it is showing valogic-federick. can anyone give the solution for this.

```
public locationValue: string = this.helper.getLocation();
  public location= this.locationValue.split("-").length>1 ? this.locationValue.split("-").splice(1):this.locationValue;
```

[image]

Comment: `str.replace(/^[^-]*/, '')` ?

Comment: @codeManiac , the code which you suuggested ,it removes the first word but it shows the hyphen and also when i click the submit button again it is showing the removed word

Comment: still didnt get solution for this can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let name = 'valogic-federick'

In your template, you can do this

```
<p (click)="sendToBackend(name)">{{name.split("-")[1]}} <p>
```

Comment: I have a form in that it is readonly input field.i think it throws error if we use interpolation in input field of a form,im not sure but i will try it

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer 
    roomObj['locationId']=this.helper.getLocation();